# Most effect way to run Drools rules

Tags: drools

Trying to learn drools.  What is the most efficient way to run drools.  Right now I have a KieContainer Bean and anytime I need to execute the rules I do the following.

```
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
kieSession.insert(record);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
kieSession.dispose();
```

Is this the proper way to do it?  Should I be creating and disposing of a session every time?  Can I reuse the session?

EDIT:  If it is acceptable to reuse a session this seems to be faster

```
FactHandle fact = kieSession.insert(record);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
kieSession.delete(fact);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reusing kieSession depends if you have general or user-specific scenarios. If you go with reuse you need to be very careful so that everything gets deleted and no previous user-specific stuff is left behind (including facts inserted by the rules etc).

It would be much safer and error-prone to recreate the kieSession every time.